# Unresolved GWT error in LibGDX HTML project

Tags: android, gwt, libgdx

I followed the tutorial [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew) but when I go to 'Problems" tab in order to make Quick Fix it says:

> The type com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint cannot be resolved. It
>   is indirectly referenced from required .class files

If I do 'Quick Fix' it appears the following :

[image: image1]

and if I press finish it goes to :

[image: image2]

I have also installed the pluging from [here](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download).

So , I don't know what to do.

---

I used Properties->Jav Build Path->add Library  and I got:

[image: image3]

But if I choose Plugin Dependancies it's empty.
If I use User Libraries I don't know what to do.

Comment: You really should use the [GDX-Setup-UI](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/gdx-setup-ui/downloads) tool recommended by developpers of LibGDX as it simplify process a lot.

Comment: Do you have the GWT extension installed? See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/usingeclipse, if not.

Comment: @P.T.:I installed the plugin from here https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download

Comment: The QuickFix should add the GWT SDK to your build path.  Try doing so manually.  Something like: Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library ... -> (pick the GWT one...)

Comment: @miNde:I used the gdx-setup-UI.

Comment: @P.T.:I can't find it.I updated.

Comment: The GWT plugin isn't completely/correctly installed.  Double-check GWT installation steps.  Note that you generally need to restart Eclipse after installing GWT.

Comment: @P.T.:I will check it agian.Yes, i restarted.

Comment: I am getting the same error even after installing GWT 2.6 eclipse plugin. Not able to find the GWT in 'Add library' options. Any clues how to add it in the build settings?

Answer (score 6):

OK, the problem was that I installed only 'GWT Designer' and 'Google Plugin for Eclipse'.

You have to install also 'SDKs'.

Now it works fine and it doesn't have an error at all.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and solved it by going in `Preferences > Google > Web Toolkit` then remove the **GWT SDK path** that showing an error (probably pointing to the wrong folder) and check the one that is shown as working and it should be ok.

Comment: :Thanks for the help.I figured it.